# The proof that L is not regular language

Tags: automata, regular-language

Let $L=\{x$| the number of $0$ in $x$ is not equal to $1$} is the language on the alphabet {$0,1$}, prove that $L$ is not RL(regular language)

I am having trouble with this. It seems that pumping lemma is not useful in this question.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189) [Please use MathJax.](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189)  For some basic information about writing math at this site, see [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189). Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) for writing a good question.

Comment: Hint: Use the closure properties of regular languages and consider the complement of L intersected with $0$\*$1$\*.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Use the relation of Nerode.
Let $L$ be a language over the alphabet $\Sigma$, (here $\Sigma=\{0,1\}$).

Define the relation $\equiv_L$ as

$u\equiv_L v :\Leftrightarrow (\forall w\in\Sigma^*: uw\in L\Leftrightarrow vw\in L).$

This is an equivalence relation and so you can form the equivalence classes.
If the index (=number of equivalence classes) is finite, then $L$ is regular.

Here the number of equivalence classes is infinite. For instance, $1$, $11$, $111$ and so on lie in different classes, e.g. $1\not\equiv_L 11$ since for $w=0$, we have $10\not\in L$ but $110\in L$.

Comment: I understand. Thank you ！

Comment: Okay good. Give some credit?